# How do I display the brand that has the biggest value, if it equals the unique identifier?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Table is A1:D11

How do I bring back the "Brand" with the highest sum of "quantity" for the "drink" "category", for each unique identifier?

Answers should be:

9929 = Lemonade

5567 = Cranberry

[image: data]

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A2:D11,
ISNUMBER(XMATCH(D2:D11,
MAXIFS(D2:D11,A2:A11,UNIQUE(A2:A11),B2:B11,"Drink")))),1,3)
```

---

Using `REDUCE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F1`

```
=REDUCE({"Unique Identifier","Brand"},TAKE(UNIQUE(A2:B11),2,1),LAMBDA(x,y,
VSTACK(x,CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A2:D11,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(D2:D11,
MAXIFS(D2:D11,A2:A11,y)))),1,3))))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

### Get Maximum Using `FILTER` and `SORT`

- In `HSTACK(uc,bc,qc)` you can choose which columns to return.
- Instead of the hard-coded `"Drink"` you could use a cell reference. The cell could have a dropdown.

```
=LET(data,A2:D20,uc,1,cc,2,bc,3,qc,4,cr,"Drink",
    d,SORT(FILTER(data,INDEX(data,,cc)=cr),qc,-1),
    du,INDEX(d,,uc),u,UNIQUE(du),
INDEX(d,XMATCH(u,du),HSTACK(uc,bc,qc)))
```

[image]